# Verticle Print Need help removing spaces

Tags: python

So in my intro to CS class we're learning with python, I know a little about it, but we have a project where we are dealing a deck of cards to 4 people, 13 cards each, and basically they play bridge, point value wise.
When printing the prof wants it to say
Used a function called reveal to print out and order numbers in list
long question, mainly the codes, thank you for the help, also, if theres anyway to clean it up i like suggestions!

```
West
    Diamonds
    J
    A
    Spades
    4
    7
    8
    10
    Q
    Hearts
    4
    9
    Q
    Clubs
    5
    A 
West has a point value of 13 points!
_______________
North
    Diamonds
    9
    10
    Q
    K
    Spades
    2
    3
    6
    J   
    Hearts
```

Like that, but mine is printing like this:

```
West
Diamonds
J
A

Spades
4
7
8
10
Q

Hearts
4
9
Q

Clubs
5
A

West has a point value of 13 points!
_______________
North
Diamonds
9
10
Q
K

Spades
2
3
6
J

Hearts
```

Here is full code

```
import random
Deck_cards = list(range(1,53))
random.shuffle(Deck_cards)

West=Deck_cards[0:13]
West.sort()
North=Deck_cards[13:26]
North.sort()
East=Deck_cards[26:39]
East.sort()
South=Deck_cards[39:52]
South.sort()
players_hand=[West, North, East, South]
Players_handname=["West","North","East","South"]

def facecard(sel):
    if sel % 13==10:
        return "J"
    elif sel % 13==11:
        return "Q"
    elif sel % 13==12:
        return "K"
    elif sel % 13==0:
        return "A"
    else:
        return (sel+1) % 13

def cardpoints(sel):
    value=0
    if sel % 13==10:
        return value+1
    elif sel % 13==11:
        return value+2
    elif sel % 13==12:
        return value+3
    elif sel % 13==0:
        return value+4
    else:
        return value

def totalpoints(x):
    sum=0
    for i in x:
        if i in range(1,53):
            sum=cardpoints(i)+sum
    return sum

def spades(x):
    print("Spades")
    list1 = []
    for i in x:
        if i in range(1,14):
            list1.append(facecard(i))
    return list1

def hearts(x):
    print("Hearts")
    list1 = []
    for i in x:
        if i in range(14,27):
            list1.append(facecard(i))
    return list1

def diamonds(x):
    print("Diamonds")
    list1 = []
    for i in x:
        if i in range(27,40):
            list1.append(facecard(i))
    return list1

def clubs(x):
    print("Clubs")
    list1 = []
    for i in x:
        if i in range(40,53):
            list1.append(facecard(i))
    return list1

def reveal(x):
    for i in x:
        print(i)
    return " "
index = 0
for i in players_hand:
    print(Players_handname[index])
    print(reveal(diamonds(i)))
    print(reveal(spades(i)))
    print(reveal(hearts(i)))
    print(reveal(clubs(i)))
    print(Players_handname[index],"has a point value of", totalpoints(i) , "points!")
    index=index+1
    print("_______________")
```

Comment: inside `reveal` you print values so you don't have to return " " and you can use `reavel(...)` instead of `print(reveal(...))`. To make indention you can add some spaces `print("      ", i)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `reveal` function, you have `print` calls, e.g. `print(i)`. This function the returns a space. When you call `reveal`, you are printing the result of the call. There's no reason to return and print an extra line with a space if you don't want it. Simply don't wrap the `reveal` call in a `print`.

```
def reveal(x):
    for i in x:
        print(i)

...

reveal(diamonds(i))
```

If you want to indent that content as well as remove extra lines, simply add tabs where necessary:

```
def hearts(x):
    print("\tHearts")
    ...
```

```
def reveal(x):
    for i in x:
        print('\t%s' % i)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, Any idea how to get it to indent like he wants?

Answer (score 0):

`print` adds new line character automaticly to every string it prints. To use something else, e.g., to print in one same line, just specify different character, for instance:

```
print(i, end=' ')
```